# Swift 別画面からのTableViewの更新

Tags: swift

Swiftでの別画面からのTableViewの更新

メインとなるListViewのtableview: UITableViewの更新を サブのPostViewから投稿するたびに行いたいのですが

PostViewの

```
@IBAction func cellAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.storyboard!

        let listView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListView") as! ListView

        let postText = textField.text!
        self.data.insert(postText, at: 0)
        userDefaults.register(defaults: ["DataStore": "default"])

        userDefaults.set(data, forKey: "DataStore")

        listView.tableView?.reloadData()

}
```

でも更新されません

```
listView.tableView?.beginUpdates()
listView.tableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)],
                              with: .automatic)
listView.tableView?.endUpdates()
```

でも更新できません

検索しても他画面からの更新はのっていません

どうしたらできるでしょうか？

追記

PostView

@IBAction func cellAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = self.storyboard!

```
    let listView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListView") as! ListView

    let postText = textField.text!
    listView.data.insert(postText, at: 0)

    listView.tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

に ボタンを設置して

押したら ListView

class ListView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var data: [String] = []

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell")!
    postcell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
    return postcell
}
```

に 移動して

という流れですが

Tab  ControllerでもどったときにTableViewが更新されていません

ListView が 0 , PostView が 1 です

質問の初期では

```
    listView.tableView?.reloadData()
```

が

```
listView.tableView?.beginUpdates()
listView.tableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)],
                              with: .automatic)
listView.tableView?.endUpdates()
```

です

追記
エラーメッセージは以下の通りです

```
2020-04-06 00:28:33.738976+0900 P1-49[83809:6003737] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x7fe823d076f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010210472b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001016a8ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102104299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010111d586 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 289
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000105e4f5dc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 171
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000010560528d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001020f0d71 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 305
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000105601fd3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1810
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010537ef0f -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 382
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010537f899 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010537fba8 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 172
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001053803c8 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052b66a8 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 472
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052b5b31 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 59
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052b1e2d -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 410
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052b1c01 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 109
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105e41e01 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052abe71 -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 506
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001052ace1a -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 213
    19  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105385dd3 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 687
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000010538653e -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 131
    21  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105387d29 -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 696
    22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105e3857d -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 656
    23  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105e49451 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 456
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001059b85ec -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 1027
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001059b8957 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 289
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001059cb5b6 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    27  UIKitCore                           0x000000010597b578 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4555
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00000001059806f6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1617
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c6222 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 904
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051ceb1a +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c5e38 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c6794 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1091
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c4b06 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 782
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c47bd -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    35  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c9502 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 576
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051ca15c _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051c9269 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00000001051ce21c -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    39  UIKitCore                           0x000000010597efd8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 514
    40  UIKitCore                           0x000000010553678a -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    41  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e240175 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    42  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e249f26 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 283
    43  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e249750 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
    44  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104476db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    45  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010447a2ba _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    46  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e27b196 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    47  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e27ae4e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 451
    48  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010e27b3e3 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 42
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010206bc11 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010206b493 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    51  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102065b4f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102065332 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    53  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b1952fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    54  UIKitCore                           0x00000001059821d2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    55  P1-49                               0x0000000100dc421b main + 75
    56  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001044eb861 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: 複数のview controllerにまたがる処理を書くときに最も大事なことは、正しいview controllerの **インスタンス** (正しい「クラス」ではありません)にアクセスすることです。(`insertRows(at:)`を使うかどうかなんてのは二の次、三の次。)あなたの現在のコードでは「メインとなるListView」のインスタンスとは別のインスタンスを作成してしまっているので、所望の動作になることはあり得ません。残念ながら「ListView」から「PostView」への遷移をどのような形で行なっているのかの情報がご質問中に示されていないため、これ以上詳しいことは書けません。ちなみに別の話になりますが、view controllerを表すクラスに「〜View」と言う名前をつけるのは混乱を招くためやめた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます 遷移はTab Controllerにておこなっています

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。その辺の情報は回答を書くためには極めて重要なものですので、コメント(こちらは「回答」ではなく「コメント」です)で示すのではなく、ご質問を編集して追記していただいた方が良いでしょう。また、「タブ切り替えで新規要素追加の画面に切り替えられる」と言うのは、あまり一般的なUIとは言えないので、全体の画面構成や各タブに対応するview controller全体のコードをお示しいただいた方が回答がつきやすいのではないかと思います。ご自身の質問は「編集」から、修正・追記ができますので、情報を追記されると良いでしょう。

Comment: できました ありがとうございます いいね! や フォロー がないのでお礼のコメントをさせていただきます

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。下手な書き方で本質的でない部分に拘って、いらぬ苦労をかけてしまって申し訳ありません。今後のためにどの辺を直したら動くようになったか、と言うのを教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: さいしょから紐付けをつなぎなおしたらできるようになりました

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり、かなり余計な手間を増やしたようで大変申し訳ありません。今後は本質的でないコードの改善なんかについて、もう少し注意深い書き方をしたいと思います。もしまた次の機会があれば、回答についてお気づきの改善ポイントなど、思うところがあればどんどんコメントしてください。

Answer (score 1):

コメントにも書きましたが、あなたのコードの中で本質的に問題があるのは、ここの部分です。

```
    let listView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListView") as! ListView
```

これでは、storyboardに定義された`ListView`のインスタンスを新たに作成してしまいます。そのインスタンスは、`UITabBarController`の0番として表示されている`ListView`のインスタンスとは別のインスタンスだと言うことになります。

そのメソッドを例えば次のようにして見てください。

```
    @IBAction func cellAdd(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let listVC = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as? ListViewController else {
            print("Cannot get listVC from tab bar controller")
            return
        }

        let postText = textField.text ?? ""
        listVC.data.insert(postText, at: 0)

        //listVC.tableView?.reloadData()
        //または
        listVC.tableView?.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    }
```

- view controllerに`ListView`なんてクラス名がついているのはあまりにも気持ちが悪いので、`ListViewController`にしてあります。あなたのプロジェクトでクラス名を変えられないなら読み替えてください。同じく`listView`を`listVC`にしてありますが、もちろんコードの動作には関係ありません。

**注** storyboardを使用しているアプリでは、ソースファイル(.swift)上でview controllerのクラス名を変更した場合には、storyboardでも対応するCustom Classの設定を更新してやる必要があります。ご質問の「追記」に記載されたエラーはこれが正しくできていない場合に起こるものなので、storyboardの設定を見直してください。

- 肝心なのは`tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0]`と言う書き方で、自画面を表示している`UITabBarController`の0番に割り当てられているview controllerを取り出すことができる、と言う点です。

---

これは直接は関係ないのですが、`ListView`(`ListViewController`)の中の以下のコードは書き換えた方が良いでしょう。

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let postcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath)
        postcell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return postcell
    }
```

`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)`と言う`for:`なしのメソッドは、Optional型を返します。それは`nil`になる可能性がある、と言うことです。iOSのメソッドの中には、「型はOptionalだけで、実は決して`nil`にはならない」なんて場合もありますが、このメソッドの場合には、実際に`nil`が返ってくる可能性があるので、`!`で強制アンラップなんかしてはいけません。

(実際iOSのバージョンによっては即座にアプリがクラッシュします。)

`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`と言う`for:`付きのメソッドを使えば、非Optionalのセルが返ってくるので、強制アンラップなんて危険なことはする必要がなくなります。

---

なお、今回のように「特定のview controllerにデータが置かれていて、それをそのview controllerのプロパティやメソッドを通じて操作する」なんてことをやっていると、画面数が増えてきたときにどうしようもなくなってくることが多いです。

(`UITabBarController`や`UINavigationController`が複雑に絡まって、どうやれば目的のview controllerにたどり着けば良いのかがとんでもなく難しくなってくるし、ちょっと画面構成を変えるだけで、あちこち書き換えないといけなくなってくる…などなど。)

特定のview controllerとは独立したデータモデルを作成して、各view controllerでは、そのデータモデルから、変更があれば通知を受け取る、なんてつくりにすると、アプリが大規模化してきた場合にも対応がしやすくなります。書き換える対象が増えますし、本来はご質問の趣旨ともだいぶ外れてしまうので、ここでは詳細には述べませんが、将来の課題とされた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます クラッシュしてしまいます

Comment: @tony さん、コメントありがとうございます。ただし、「クラッシュしてしまいます」とだけ書かれても何がどうなったのか全くわかりません。掲載のコードは実際にXcodeでプロジェクトを作成して動作を確認したものです。何をしたら、どこでどんなメッセージと共にクラッシュしたのかの情報をお知らせください。

Comment: 0


AppDeligateでクラッシュします クラス名もすべて変更しました

Comment: @tony さん、残念ながら「何をしたら」(例えば「アプリを起動してxxxボタンを押した」などが聞きたいことです)にも「どんなメッセージ」にも答えていただいていません。また「クラス名もすべて変更」とありますが、.swiftファイルのクラス名だけでなく、storyboard内のクラス名も全て変更されたでしょうか?なお、回答欄は質問や他の回答に関する情報を書く場所ではありませんので、そちらは削除していただいて、ご質問内容を再度編集して情報を追記していただいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: すみません アプリを起動した瞬間にクラッシュしてしまいます

Comment: @tony さん、デバッグコンソールにはどんなメッセージが表示されていますか?

Comment: ながすきて記載できません 6400文字

Comment: @tony さん、ですから先ほども書いたようにご質問を編集して追記をお願いします。

Comment: エラー内容を追記しました

Comment: @tony さん、エラー内容の追記ありがとうございました。これはこちらの中途半端な書き方に責任があるとは思うのですが、「.swiftファイルのクラス名」を変更した後に、storyboard内の各view controllerもその新しいクラス名を指すように変更しなければいけないのに、それが行われていないときに出るエラーです。storyboard上で各Custom Classに`ListView`や`PostView`を設定したときのことを思い出して、そのクラス名を新しいものに変更して見てください。

Comment: 変更しても出ます

Comment: @tony さん、全く同じメッセージが出るなら、それは正しく変更できていないせいだと思われます。もう一度見直して見てください。Custom Classが`ListViewController`(.swiftファイル内に記載したクラス名)になっており、Inherit Module From Targetにチェックは入っていますか?

Comment: @tony さん、こちらでは`ListView`と言う、あなたが示されたクラス名のままで動くようにしたプロジェクトのクラス名を付け替えると言うことを何度かやっていますが、完全に同じエラーを再現することができていません。従って、今まで示した意外に具体的にどこをチェックしてほしいと言うことが書けないのですが、Xcodeがstoryboardの状態をうまく管理できなくなってエラーになったことはあったので、以下のことを試してもらえるでしょうか?■storyboard上でCustom Classを正しく書き換える。■全てのIBOutlet, IBActionを一旦外す。■Xcodeを一旦終了してから、再度起動して同じプロジェクトを開く。■IBOutlet, IBActionをつなぎなおす。本質的でない指摘を説明もなく入れたせいで余計な苦労をさせてしまって申し訳ないのですが、試して見てください。